# building a search-module: using linear logic- data

Tags: ruby, algorithm, logic

I want basically to list next schedules (time_tables) from a given train-number. 
By entering the train number. From there start looking for the rest of its linear route, the train will get different schedules a long the way). When the first time_table ends, the other time_table starts, and so on.

Now Im getting this ERROR as soon it gets in the inner loop:

> undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

```
require 'date'

Time_tables =   [
    { name: '01251', start_date: '2014-04-24 22:03:00', start_location: 'A', end_date: '2014-04-24 22:10:00', end_location: 'BC' },
    { name: '05012', start_date: '2014-04-24 22:20:00', start_location: 'RI', end_date: '2014-04-24 23:10:00', end_location: 'XX' },
    { name: '03232', start_date: '2014-04-24 17:10:00', start_location: 'X', end_date: '2014-04-24 20:10:00', end_location: 'B' },
    { name: '02435', start_date: '2014-04-24 17:10:00', start_location: 'Z', end_date: '2014-04-24 20:10:00', end_location: 'B' },
    { name: '04545', start_date: '2014-04-24 22:15:00', start_location: 'BC', end_date: '2014-04-24 22:20:00', end_location: 'RI' },
    { name: '03545', start_date: '2014-04-24 23:15:00', start_location: 'XX', end_date: '2014-04-25 00:10:00', end_location: 'E' }
]


def finding_next_stops(time_tables, train_number)
  #variables:
  @referenced_point
  joined_time_tables = []

  time_tables.sort_by! do |time_table|
    DateTime.parse(time_table[:start_date]).to_time
  end

  #looking for the given time_table
  time_tables.each  do |i|
    if i[:name] == train_number
      @referenced_point = i
    end
  end

  #adding the time_table to the container and then starting the search from this item

  0.upto(time_tables.size-1) do |i|
    #If it's empty I wanna start with the referenced_point(this time_table)
    if joined_time_tables.empty?
      p  'gets in once!'
      middle_hand_container = @referenced_point
    else
      middle_hand_container = [time_tables[i]]
    end


    0.upto(i-1) do |j|
      j_end_date = joined_time_tables[j][-1][:end_date]
      i_start_date = time_tables[i][:start_date]
      if j_end_date <= i_start_date
        if joined_time_tables[j][-1][:end_location].eql? time_tables[i][:start_location]
          #if longest[j].size + 1 > long_for_i.size  # shall I check this ?

          middle_hand_container = joined_time_tables[j] + [time_tables[i]]
          #end
        end
      end
    end
    joined_time_tables[i] = middle_hand_container
  end
  return joined_time_tables[-1]
end


finding_next_stops(Time_tables, '05012')
```

if I enter this: '05012'- train_number I should get:

- { name: '05012', start_date: '2014-04-24 22:20:00', start_location:
  'RI', end_date: '2014-04-24 23:10:00', end_location: 'XX' }, { name:
  '03545', start_date: '2014-04-24 23:15:00', start_location: 'XX',
  end_date: '2014-04-24 00:10:00', end_location: 'E' }

if I enter this: '04545' train_number I should get:

- { name: '04545', start_date: '2014-04-24 22:15:00', start_location:
  'BC', end_date: '2014-04-24 22:20:00', end_location: 'RI' }, { name:
  '05012', start_date: '2014-04-24 22:20:00', start_location: 'RI',
  end_date: '2014-04-24 23:10:00', end_location: 'XX' }, { name:
  '03545', start_date: '2014-04-24 23:15:00', start_location: 'XX',
  end_date: '2014-04-25 00:10:00', end_location: 'E' }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
j_end_date = joined_time_tables[j][-1][:end_date]
```

`join_time_tables` contains an array of hashes. `[j]` returns a hash, so `[-1]` returns nil. You should either remove the `[j]` or the `[-1]` (I'm not sure which, as the code is too complex).

**Update**

I think your aim for `@referenced_point` to be an array, but actually it is not:

```
time_tables.each  do |i|
  if i[:name] == train_number
    @referenced_point = i
  end
end
```

You should wrap it in an array for your code to work:

```
middle_hand_container = @referenced_point
```

I do think, though, that your code needs a serious refactoring.

Comment: After your code works, I suggest you post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/